# AngularJS - Dropdown Select Values are not in Order with ng-repeat

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select drop down with the following data; (This is also the output to the console in Chrome).

```
{
    8: "Something", 
    9: "Something Again!", 
    10: "And again", 
    11: "And again!", 
    12: "etc...", 
    13: "etc etc...", 
}
```

The html and angular for the select drop down;

```
<select name="name" ng-model="choosen"> 
   <option value="">Please Select</select>
   <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" value="[[key]]">[[value]]</option>
</select>
```

The data is got from using the following query within Laravel (4.2) using the lists function;

```
Model::lists('name','id');
```

For some reason the data for the drop down gets reordered within my drop down to;

```
<select name="name" ng-model="choosen"> 
   <option value="">Please Select</select>
   <option value="10">And again</option>
   <option value="11">And again!</option>
   <option value="12">etc...</option>
   <option value="13">etc etc...</option>
   <option value="8">Something</option>
   <option value="9">Something Again!</option>
</select>
```

How do i make the output from the ng-repeat run through the order of the data in the correct numerical order?

Like so;

```
<select name="name" ng-model="choosen"> 
   <option value="">Please Select</select>
   <option value="8">Something</option>
   <option value="9">Something Again!</option>
   <option value="10">And again</option>
   <option value="11">And again!</option>
   <option value="12">etc...</option>
   <option value="13">etc etc...</option>
</select>
```

Plunkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HxlMfVq4Y3jeHvhV8mFs?p=preview)

Comment: ->orderBy('id', 'asc') ?
ngRepeat doesn't reorder your data so the data you pass to the ngRepeat are in that order (sorry for the wordplay)

Comment: @originof The order of the data is correct from the controller to the angular, the console output is the order of the data. But when put into the ng-repeat the data is moved around.

Comment: Are you sure ? Try to write a plunkr

Comment: @originof Im very much positive.

Comment: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HxlMfVq4Y3jeHvhV8mFs?p=preview)

Comment: Probably the workaround is http://plnkr.co/edit/S8BiSPy9axQobSZVwk3D?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that ngRepeat order the data by the $$hash, probably the workaround is to use a function that list the keys and then iterate over them:

```
 $scope.keys = function(obj){
  return obj? Object.keys(obj) : [];
 }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/S8BiSPy9axQobSZVwk3D?p=preview

Comment: You can also create a filter that do the same job