# AngularJS ng-options sorting according to value

Tags: angularjs

I have data as 
{"1":"A","2":"B","3":"C", "18":"X","19":"Y","20":"Z","21":"AAA","22":"BCB","23":"TTT"}

I have populated in selcet box as

```
 ng-options="value for (key, value) in poetList | orderBy : 'value'"
```

I mean I wish to sort it using value or as a key but in proper way. Since the key is string format. Its sorting as 1,12,123,2,23,224 in this way. I tried to put orderBy filter but that doesn't work. How to do this type of sorting

Answer (score 0):

I had an error like this; A potential solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423127/angularjs-dropdown-select-values-with-ng-repeat);

```
$scope.keys = function(obj){
    return obj? Object.keys(obj) : [];
}
```

And within the ng-repeat on a option tag;

```
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option ng-repeat="k in keys(data)" value="{{ k }}">{{ data[k] }}</option>
```

Its to do with the ngRepeat ordering the data by the $$hash, not the key itself.

Comment: I wish to use ng-options instead of ng-repeat because it halts with first option empty in various cases.